# Firebase cloud messaging api v1 Expected OAuth 2 access token

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, firebase-cloud-messaging

I guess firebase disabled legacy api for new users. They want us to use v1 api.
When i try to send notification with postman i get this .

```
 "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
    }
```

I have service accounts, server key etc. But i dont now how to migrate .
I'm using dart-shelf backend and flutter.

For postman this is my configuration.

```
Authorization = Bearer +AAAAA..token
```

This is the body that i sent

```
{
  "message":{
     "token":"<generated token by flutter>",
     "notification":{
       "body":"This is an FCM notification message!",
       "title":"FCM Message"
     }
  }
}
```

And this is how i generate token for specific device on flutter.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) async {
      _init();
    });
    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
        const AndroidInitializationSettings('ic_launcher');
    var initialzationSettingsAndroid =
        const AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(android: initialzationSettingsAndroid);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            notification.hashCode,
            notification.title,
            notification.body,
            NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                channel.id,
                channel.name,
                color: Colors.blue,
                // TODO add a proper drawable resource to android, for now using
                //      one that already exists in example app.
                icon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher",
              ),
            ));
      }
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (_) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text(notification.title!),
                content: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [Text(notification.body!)],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            });
      }
    });

    getToken();
  }
```

My backend on google cloud computing.

Answer (score 2):

I found solution for my problem. I will leave here solution for who needs it.

Your headers and body of your post is correct. You should exchange your authorization code for tokens.

Here is how you can test

1 - Open OAuth 2.0 Playground https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

2- Input your scope which is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging (After you submit your scope it is gonna authorize to your google account)

3- Enter your authorization code (device's token which is given by firebase when u did your configuration for your UI) and click "Exchange authorization code for token"

Playground will give you access token and refresh token. You should put your access token like Bearer ya29... .

After you able to send notification with postman. But for your software you should automate exchanging tokens in your code.

Check out this repo for your programming language .

https://github.com/googleapis?q=auth

Comment: Playground not for Production.

Comment: Yes thats why i declared the github repo for production.